# JQuery search keyword and style closest specified html element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a Chrome Extension that highlights specific keywords.

Let's say I'm on a website with the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Specific keyword.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <h1>Another Title</h1>
        <p>Some copy.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following JQuery will search for the term "specific keyword" and apply a background-color to each `<div>`.

```
$( "div:contains('specific keyword')" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Instead, I'd like to search for the keyword and only apply the style to the closest specified html element e.g. in this case `class="one"`. Is this possible?

Comment: CSS structure? or did you mean html structure?

Comment: You're right, I mean html structure. I've edited the question, so hopefully this will clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding greater than:

```
$( "div>:contains('specific keyword')" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

This will only target the closest div to the keyword (not the container).

It may also be usefull to know that contains is case sensitive, so you can add this if you would like to make it case-insensitive:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Comment: Good solution and bonus points for the case sensitive information, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$( "div:contains('specific keyword')" ).closest(".one").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

or if you always want the direct parent generally, use [**parent()**](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$( "div:contains('specific keyword')" ).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: Using `.closest("div")` or `.parent()` seems to target `.container()`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the easiest solution be using the [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector.

```
$("div:contains('specific keyword')").parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

The parent selector can also take a selector

```
$("div:contains('specific keyword')").parent(".one").css( "background-color", "red" );
```